# How to connect a button in an $ionicPopup to the controller that is invoking it?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-popup

I know ideally using an Actionsheet will solve my problem here, but I want to know if it is possible to connect a button in an ionicPopup to the controller that is invoking it via ng-click directive.
I originally thought the ng-click directive will introduce the $scope of the controller, but it doesn't seem to be the case. So does that mean we cannot connect buttons to the controller in an ionicPopup?

Comment: I clearly don't understand your question

Comment: Some code would be helpful...

Comment: Did you manage to find a solutions?

Answer (score 0):

[$ionicPopup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/) returns promises.

Let's say your view has a button which invokes (**ng-click**) a method in your controller:

```
<button class="button button-primary" ng-click="showConfirm()">Confirm</button>
```

In your controller you would invoke your popup doing something like this:

```
$scope.showConfirm = function() {
   var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
     title: 'Consume Ice Cream',
     template: 'Are you sure you want to eat this ice cream?'
   });
   confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
     if(res) {
       console.log('You are sure');
     } else {
       console.log('You are not sure');
     }
   });
 };
```

When a user has tapped on one of the 2 buttons in the confirm dialog you can read the result and do some other things.

```
confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
     if(res) {
       console.log('You are sure');
     } else {
       console.log('You are not sure');
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand 100% your question, but I guess you need a button within a "$ ionicPopup" call a function of the controller? if so, I leave this.

```
$ionicPopup.show({
    title: 'Información View',
    subTitle: '',
    content: 'Content'
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Exit',
      onTap: function(e) {
        //Call function by pressing button exit
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Ok',
      type: 'button-positive',
      onTap: function(e) {
        //Call function by pressing button Ok
      }
    }, ]
  })
}
```

Comment: I want to change the $state on tap of the button but it is not working. Any advice?

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Finally I got it working. I had wrong `views` property set in the state.